# AWS Fargate services and Service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

In my AWS ECS cluster I have two services:

- nginx
- myapp

And then in nginx I want to connect to a container in `myapp`. I have enabled both services with Service Discovery, but I fail to connect to `myapp`:

I use `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `myapp.containername` but to no avail and all of them cannot be resolved. How should I connect nginx to `myapp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with two things:

1- Services were nested in different availability zones (when creating a service, after VPC selection, it asks for your desired subnets)

2- Inbound rule in Security Group, had a source of 0.0.0.0/0, I changed it to Anywhere and it worked.